# WSDL Testing using soapUI

Tags: apex, soap-api, wsdl2apex, apexrest, partner-wsdl

I am testing a custom WSDL using SoapUI. when i try to run the wsdl it consumed the salesforce record but noting displayed on SoapUI.But when i checked in the salesforce it shows that the record has been consumed.

What could be the reason for this.Why the soapUI deosn't display the xml of fetched record?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the tags of the OP:

- WSDL2Apex : You generated an outbound webservice client in apex
- Partner-WSDL : You call (inbound) the SF partner API

Can you describe what you exactly want to do?

What is the raw input and output specified in the SoapUI HTTP log?

Is this valid SOAP output?

What did you expect based on the WSDL? What do you return in SF?

Answer (score 0):

i found the mistake. The reason is i haven't included a field in my query .this field i am using in my filter criteria.As there is no field it always return null as a result the output is empty.It a human error.☺